# How avoid loading unused beans in springBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testing, junit, spring-boot-test

I have a test class like this there I want to test only controller layer:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var myService: MyService

    private val path = "/api/v1/myapp"

    @LocalServerPort
    private val serverPort = 0

    @Test
    fun foo() { 
       // prepare request
       // do some call
       val response = testRestTemplate.exchange(...)
       //check response 
    }
 }
```

When I start the app I see that it loads all the application beans but we don't need. it tries to load all the different components in my application. This includes beans which interact with external systems and need credentials in order to connect etc.
Looks like it is redundant.

Is there way to avoid loading redundant beans ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just unit test controller layer on request and response just use [@WebMvcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html)

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent`, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans).

> By default, tests annotated with @WebMvcTest will also auto-configure Spring Security and MockMvc (include support for HtmlUnit WebClient and Selenium WebDriver). For more fine-grained control of MockMVC the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation can be used.

> Typically @WebMvcTest is used in combination with `@MockBean` or `@Import` to create any collaborators required by your `@Controller` beans.

> If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use MockMVC, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` rather than this annotation.

> When using JUnit 4, this annotation should be used in combination with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

here is an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest)

Comment: I tried to mark my test with
`
@WebMvcTest(MyController::class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient
`
But I get the error `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate' available:`

Comment: why do u wanna use `TestRestTemplate` ? use `MockMvc` as shown in example

Comment: I already have thousands lines of code which depends on TestRestTemplate

Comment: `TestRestTemplate` bean will be available if u use `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and if use `@SpringBootTest` you will have all beans loaded. U can also create `TestRestTemplate` object

Comment: var testRestTemplate = TestRestTemplate(); for just tests @gstackoverflow

Comment: And one more issue with annotation @LocalServerPort

Comment: I missed that, actually i will recommend changing all `TestRestTemplate` to `MockMvc` that's the correct way of doing it while using `@WebMvcTest`

Comment: I agree but it will take too much time to rewrite all the tests. I think it should be possible